# Facebook wall post from an App via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I have a Timeline App that creates a wall posting via the Graph API.   The wall posting indicates that the posting was created by the App, which is fine.   However, the link for the app points to the Canvas page: http://apps.facebook.com/app_name_space.

I need the link to point to  the timeline version of the App:  http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGENAME/PAGEID?sk=app_APPID

I have tried the "actions" parameter on the Post call, but that didn't solve the problem.

---

**Redirecting the Canvas page**

Since you cannot use a 301 redirect for this purpose, here is what I did (asp.net):

1) Create a folder named 'canvas' under the website root.

2) Add a default.aspx file to the folder (can't use a static file as an app landing page)

3) Add the following javascript to the head tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

       var parentPageName = '<%=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ParentPageName"]%>';
       var appID = '<%=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AppID"]%>';
       var myHREF = "http://www.facebook.com/" + parentPageName + "?sk=app_" + appID;
       top.location.href = myHREF;                                                        
</script>
```

4) Change your App Canvas url to point to the 'canvas' folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it works, the 'via' link goes to your app, not to an arbitrary page the app is installed on, because it could be installed on any Facebook page.

Redirect users that land on the canvas app to the page tab, if that's what you want

Comment: True enough, but why not put that under the control of the app creator?

Good suggestion on the redirect.  Thanks.

Comment: You control almost every other aspect of the post, though - practically the only thing you can't override is the name and URL of the app used to make the post